# Python Parse log file string into txt file

Tags: python, parsing

I have written a simple Python Script that parses a log and prints a string if a line is equal to a mac address.

My next step is to parse out the log file into a txt file.

Is there a way to create a variable for each mac address of the access point so that when it parses out into text file, it will not show mac address it will show the AP name, and user name?

here is an example line

```
[2014-07-22 10:21:06,821] <inform_stat-3> WARN  event  - [event] User[78:a3:e4:3b:bd:3d] roams from AP[dc:9f:db:1a:60:64] to AP[dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95] on "channel 11(ng)"
```

My code is currently as follows

```
for line in open("system.log"):
    if "e4:98:d6:27:4c:b6" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the input/output you want? Along with whatever you've coded so far that isn't working?

Comment: Where is the username & AP name coming from - do you have a mapping of some sort?

Comment: All i want from the output is a line with the User, going from one AP to a Other Ap

Comment: But you said you wanted names not mac address - how are you getting those?

Comment: i have a list, of all the Access points, if you could leave it blank i could fill the names of the AP.

Comment: So create a dictionary of mac to name then look it up when you parse the line.

Comment: yeah, i am a beginner in python so, i am having some trouble with this.

Comment: do you want your output like this:  User[78:a3:e4:3b:bd:3d]<space>  AP[dc:9f:db:1a:60:64]<space>AP[dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95] or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the dictionary:

```
dd = {'78:a3:e4:3b:bd:3d' : 'Joe Smith',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:60:64' : 'Server1',
      'dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95' : 'Server1'}

dat = '[2014-07-22 10:21:06,821] <inform_stat-3> WARN  event  - [event] User[78:a3:e4:3b:bd:3d] roams from AP[dc:9f:db:1a:60:64] to AP[dc:9f:db:1a:2d:95] on "channel 11(ng)"'
aps = []
for elem in dat.split():
    if elem.startswith('User['):
        uname = dd.get(elem[5:-1], 'Unknown')
    if elem.startswith('AP['):
        aps.append(dd.get(elem[3:-1], 'Unknown'))
```

now you should have enough information to print to the text file